# ignore mysql schema on replication before moving from mysql 5.6 to mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, replication

I am planning to move from mysql 5.6 to mysql 5.7, so I going to upgrade one of my slaves instances to 5.7, and later on to switch it to a master.

Should I need to ignore mysql db before upgrading mysql 5.6 to 5.7 on this slave ?

```
replicate-ignore-db = mysql
replicate-wild-ignore-table=mysql.%
```

If so to what should I pay attention after upgrading or before switching my master to 5.7 (beside testing mysql 5.7 with my application)?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is my.cnf:

```
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[mysqld]
read_only
max_connections=2500
log-slave-updates=true
port=3306
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock  
datadir=/data/mysql
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_file_format=Barracuda
innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_support_xa=0
innodb_io_capacity=2500
innodb_adaptive_hash_index=1
innodb_doublewrite=0
innodb_read_io_threads=8
innodb_write_io_threads=8
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
table_open_cache=2500
innodb_open_files=10000
open_files_limit=10000
optimizer_search_depth=0
innodb_file_per_table
max_connect_errors=10000000000
max_connections=2500
long_query_time = 1000
max_allowed_packet = 16M
binlog_cache_size = 1M
max_heap_table_size = 500M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 8M
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_limit = 0
query_cache_type=0
tmp_table_size = 1200M
max_tmp_tables=250 
long_query_time = 2
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 42G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_log_file_size = 400M
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 100
server-id = 102
expire_logs_days        = 12
max_binlog_size         = 100M
relay-log=/data/binlogs/linuxdb1023306_r.-relay-bin
relay-log-index=/data/binlogs/linuxdb1023306-relay-bin.index
log-bin= /data/binlogs/linuxdb1023306-bin
binlog_format=row
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
max_connections=2500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I need to ignore mysql db before upgrading mysql 5.6 to 5.7 on this slave?

No, you should not.  MySQL should handle everything correctly when the replica is newer than the master by not more than one major release, e.g. 5.6 to 5.7 -- just like you have here.

The fact you appear to be using the `ROW` binlog format is good, but be sure you're using it on the master, too, for the best chance of continuous clean replication.

And do have a good cry while reading the official [list of caveats and breaking changes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html).  Most of them are well-intentioned, at least.

Comment: can you please have a look on this question [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175972/mysql-5-7-replication-
slave-parallel-workers-and-slave-pending-jobs-size-max) , thank you !