# mysql 5.7 replication - slave_parallel_workers and slave_pending_jobs_size_max

Tags: mysql, replication

I am using `slave_parallel_type = LOGICAL_CLOCK` and `slave_parallel_workers = 20` to achieve replication performance.

Lets say I am using `m4.4xlarge` with 16 cores and 64GB memory for the master and the slave:

1. As far I understand these`slave_parallel_type` and `slave_parallel_workers` parameter should be only on the slave, right ?
2. What value `slave_parallel_workers` parameter should have? 16 as number of cores ? (I test it with 20 and I got nice performance).
3. Any suggestion about the slave_pending_jobs_size_max ?
4. sync_binlog=1 should be on both master and slave to increase group commits and increase the potential to execute queries in parallel?

> ```
> slave_parallel_workers=20
> slave_parallel_type = LOGICAL_CLOCK
> slave_pending_jobs_size_max=1G
> sync_binlog=1
> max_allowed_packet = 256M
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Depending on your workload, a much smaller number may work just as well.  Too large a number leads to contention; too small leads to slow replication.  (20 seems "high")

Comment: @RickJames thank you, do you know maybe if slave_parallel_type and slave_parallel_workers parameters should be only on the slave?

Comment: I think the answer is that they are defined in the section "System Variables Used on Replication Slaves" of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html .  Note also the name of that page: "replication-options-slave.html".